# Any way to solve version conflicts with DLL when using remoting. Dotnet framework 4.8

Tags: c#, dll

I am looking for some advice on the following problem:

For authorization requests I have developed an "authorization provider interface" to be able to couple different implementations of authorization-authorites to our applications, for example an implementation that gets its data from a database or another one that runs as a service in the network and is addressed via dotnet remoting (= authorization service).

The implementation required for the respective use case is bound to the corresponding application via the Unity tool from Microsoft by means of inversion-of-control/dependency-injection, in this case the previously mentioned implementation by remoting.

```
...
<alias alias="Authority.Generic"
       type="app_core.web.security.authorization.IAuthorizationProvider, app_core" />

<alias alias="Authority.RemotingService"
       type="app_core.web.security.authorization.RemotingServiceAuthorizationProvider, app_core" />

<register type="Authority.Generic" mapTo="Authority.RemotingService">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
    <constructor>
        <param name="Endpoint">
            <value value="tcp://server:port/Authorization" />
        </param>
    </constructor>
</register>
```

The interface of the authorization provider is stored in a central DLL (= app_core.dll), which is available in all our applications as well as in the authorization service.

If only the case occurs that for one application (="App1") the DLL has to be extended and as a result the DLL gets a new version number, this application can no longer communicate with the authorization service via remoting.
When the service is provided with the new version of the DLL, communication with the application "App1" works again, however, communication then fails for all other applications "App2" ... "AppN", and so on, where still the old version of the DLL is included.

Since we run a lot of different applications, this now means that we always have to distribute the changed DLL to all applications, even though these applications don't actually need the new functions of the DLL.

[image: Application scheme]

I am now looking for a solution by which

1. I can leave the interface for the authorization providers in the
   app_core.dll
2. without signing/strong-naming the dll

and tell the authorization service to ignore any difference in the version number of the requesting DLL.

In a configuration file of another project I found the following section for the Newtonsoft library:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Can I possibly solve my problem via such a configuration? I tried but was unsuccessful.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a code example for this case due to its complexity.

Comment: Must you change the AssemblyVersion of app_core.dll?  Incrementing the AssemblyVersion is _supposed to_ break things.  If you modify an assembly without incrementing the AssemblyVerion, you might get runtime MissingMethodExceptions, etc.  See eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/visualstudio/general/assembly-version-assembly-file-version

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I never asked myself this question because the assignment of the assembly version number is defined within the company's development guidelines.  Now I will question the procedure and test whether that solves the problem.

Comment: Is there any chance that the objects sent over the remoting channel are different between versions? Because I think remoting uses BinaryFormatter by default for serialization, and this has notoriously bad backward compatibility.

Comment: Hello @JonasH. No, when the app_core.dll was extended, then only in the form that new functions were added. The interface of the authorization provider as well as its data, functions and procedures are / were the same across all versions.